# Cannot find property on object that exists

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have an array of objects and am trying to manipulate it and am getting an error that the property RptFile does not exist.  I have checked the spelling and everything and am baffled as to what is going on.

The code giving the error:

```
$AllContents | Where-Object {$_.RptFile -eq 'CB-Officer Trial New'} 

AllContents | Get-Member returns:


TypeName: Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name         MemberType   Definition                                            
----         ----------   ----------                                            
Equals       Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                        
GetHashCode  Method       int GetHashCode()                                     
GetType      Method       type GetType()                                        
ToString     Method       string ToString()                                     
RptFile      NoteProperty System.String RptFile=ABL - Branch5206 Daily OD Report
TotalSeconds NoteProperty System.String TotalSeconds=25
```

So the property does exist. Any idea what is going on?  If I just type $AllContents, I get a list with the property also.

Answer (score 4):

What is your value for `Set-StrictMode` can you test to remove strict mode before your code?

```
Set-StrictMode -Off
```

What are the results for :

```
Get-Member -InputObject $AllContents

Get-Member -InputObject $AllContents[0].RptFile
```

Comment: It won't let me post it all, but the first says   TypeName: System.Object[].  The second gives    TypeName: System.String.  Both  lists properties of rank, syncroot, length and a few others.  No rptfile property.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me, turns out I had `Set-StrictMode` in my machine's `profile.ps1` (and the program that executed the script foolishly omitted `-NoProfile`)

Answer (score 3):

Try first

```
$AllContents[0].RptFile = '<value>'
```

if not something like this should help:

```
[Your.Interface.Implemented.Explicitly].GetProperty("RptFile").SetValue($AllContents[0], '<value>',$null)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will be helpful, and I'm sure this is akin to thread necromancy, but I just ran into the same issue, and this was the first result on google.

I created the same problem with the following code:

```
Class A_Class
{
    [String] $AProperty

    A_Class()
    {
        $this.AProperty = "Something"
    }
}

Class Collection_Of_A_Class
{
    [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[int,A_Class[]]] $Objects #a dictionary, where i intended each entry to be a A_Class, but which is defined as an array of A_Class

    Collection_Of_A_Class()
    {
        $this.Objects = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[int], A_Class[]]]'
    }

    [void]AddObject()
    {
        $this.Objects.Add(0,[A_Class]::New())
    }
}

$myCollection = [Collection_Of_A_Class]::New()

$myCollection.AddObject()

$myCollection.Objects[0].AProperty = "SomethingElse"
```

Basically, I was attempting to access the property of a member of an array as though it was a single object. Because the dictionary's data type is hard typed to an array, it took my single object and forced it to be an array.
As a result, my property (as addressed) really doesn't exist. Changing the dictionary definition to:

```
[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[int,A_Class]] $Objects
```

and the instantiation to:

```
$this.Objects = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[int],[A_Class]]'
```

fixes the problem.

You can also fix the problem by accessing via:

$myCollection.Objects[0][0].AProperty = "SomethingElse"

In this case, I've accessed dictionary object with index 0, and element 0 of the array stored there. In this case the property actually exists (as addressed).

I would check your code for a situation which results in the elements in $AllContents being arrays, rather than individual objects (or results in this some of the time, such as assuming a prior command would only return one object, when it returns numerous objects).

Answer (score 1):

```
$rptFile = $AllContents | Select -Expand RptFile | Where { $_ eq 'CB-Officer Trial New' }
```

Comment: That gives a list, which is what I get when I type $AllContents. I am trying to filter.

Comment: add a pipe with a where clause:

Comment: Property 'RptFile' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.
At line:1 char:37
+ $rptFile = $AllContents | Where {$_. <<<< RptFile -eq 'CB-Officer Trial New'}  | Select -Expand RptFile
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (.:OperatorToken) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict

Comment: You can add the where clause at the end:

Comment: If I do: $AllContents | Where-Object {$_.TotalSeconds -ge 20  }, I get results with 1 error in the middle. Is it possible there are a lot of NULL values for RptFile and that is why I am getting errors? Or maybe the array has items that aren't the same object with the RptFile property?

Comment: Best as I can tell, it is a bug. I got out of Powershell and back in and it works fine.  However, it is being dot source by another script and giving the same error in that case.  That is why I am baffled. I am not new to Powershell.

Comment: I'll add that even though it gives that error, it seems to successfully do the WHERE.